# Implement IEquatable equals correctly to compare 2 collections of the same type

Tags: c#

I want to compare 2 collections of the type User.cs

The result is OK so far that means I get my 3 changed user objects in the linq query.

But I am not sure wether my implementation is really correct. My concern come from the many google questions and different samples about IEquatable and many people seem to implement/override it in different ways.

1.) In the both Equals methods should I use the == operator to compare the properties or the property.Equals method or the StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals. Does this matter at all here at this place just for a correct comparison (no performance question here)

2.) Is It ok to just concat the properties in the GetHashCode. Seems stupid as it works only because I use a string property as the first property :P Is there a better method?
I have also read that I should not use the xor operator but not really why or I did not understand it...

```
public class User : IEquatable<User>
    {
        public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
        public bool IsLicenced { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(User other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(this.Name, other.Name) &&
                StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(this.Text, other.Text) &&
                StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(this.IsDisabled, other.IsDisabled) &&
                StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(this.IsLicenced, other.IsLicenced);
        }

        // override this too when the static String.Equals somewhere is used on the BO User to be on the safe side!
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
             User user = obj as User;
            if (user != null)
            {
                return this.Name == user.Name &&
                    this.Text == user.Text &&
                    this.IsDisabled == user.IsDisabled &&
                    this.IsLicenced == user.IsLicenced;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            string uniquePropertiesString = Text + Name + IsLicenced + IsDisabled;
            return uniquePropertiesString.GetHashCode();
        }
    }



    var usersOld = new List<User>();
    var userOld1 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Name = "Hans1", Text = "Alt1" };
    var userOld2 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Name = "Hans2", Text = "Alt2" };
    var userOld3 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Name = "Hans3", Text = "Alt3" };
    var userOld4 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Name = "Hans4", Text = "Alt4" };

    usersOld.Add(userOld1);
    usersOld.Add(userOld2);
    usersOld.Add(userOld3);
    usersOld.Add(userOld4);

    var usersToday = new List<User>();
    var userNew1 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = true, Name = "Hans1", Text = "Neu1" };
    var userNew2 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Name = "Hans2", Text = "Alt2" }; // DID NOT CHANGE
    var userNew3 = new User { IsDisabled = false, IsLicenced = false, Name = "Hans3", Text = "Neu3" };
    var userNew4 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = true, Name = "Hans4", Text = "Neu4" };

    usersToday.Add(userNew1);
    usersToday.Add(userNew2);
    usersToday.Add(userNew3);
    usersToday.Add(userNew4);

    List<User> changedUsers = usersOld.Join(usersToday, o => o.Name, n => n.Name,
                        (o, n) => new { Old = o, New = n })
                  .Where(pair => !pair.Old.Equals(pair.New))
                  .Select(u => new User { Name = u.New.Name, Text = u.New.Text, IsLicenced = u.New.IsLicenced, IsDisabled = u.New.IsDisabled })
                  .ToList();

    // Assert => The changedUsers should have 3 changed users
```

Comment: when comparing `Objects` use the `.Equals()` method when comparing values use the `==`

Comment: There's a more important issue here. If you are using properties to calculate hash codes, the properties really should be immutable. If not, this can lead to all sorts of problems if the properties involved in the calculation are changed after the object in question has been inserted into a HashSet, Dictionary etc.

Comment: The docs say that you should not use GetHashCode over mutable objects unless (a) You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable; or (b) You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code.  IMO, ensuring that mutation does not occur at the wrong time is bad juju as it isn't enforceable.

Comment: @spender I can not make the props immutable because there are public setters.. When the changedUsers are found out they are afair just written into an extra database table.

Comment: @spender When you look at the code you can see that changedUsers is a new List with new Member objects. So in my opinion changing this new List`s members properties should be fine. What do you think?